# react scroll to component

Tags: reactjs, scroll

I have 3 components which is my site. Each component js-file is loaded and all 3 shows on one page like this:

Topmenu
SectionOne
SectionTwo

In the Topmenu component I have a menu only. I’ve tried to setup the scrollToComponent onClick at a menu field (SectionOne). But I cannot figure out how to get it to scroll to SectionOne when clicked?

I know this.sectionOne is a ref to an internal ref, right? But how to direct it to a ref inside the “sectionOne.js” file?

I have the following inside my TopMenu.js file

```
     onClick={() => scrollToComponent(this.sectionOne , { offset: 0, align: 'top', duration: 1500})}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To forward the `ref` to somewhere inside the component, you can use the logic of [`forwardRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-to-dom-components).

This means that we create the ref in the parent component and pass the same to the component which passes it down to DOM element inside it.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.section1 = React.createRef();
    this.section2 = React.createRef();
    this.scrollToContent = this.scrollToContent.bind(this);
  }
  scrollToContent(content) {
    switch(content) {
      case 1:
        this.section1.current.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
        break;
      case 2:
        this.section2.current.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <main>
        <Menu goTo={this.scrollToContent} />
        <div className='main'>
          <Section1 ref={this.section1} />
          <Section2 ref={this.section2} />
        </div>
      </main>
    );
  }
}
```

and then, inside `Section1`,

```
const Section1 = React.forwardRef((props, ref)=>{
  return (
    <section ref={ref} className='section'>
      <p>Section 1</p>
    </section>
  );
});
```

You can see a working sample [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-q2rjkc?file=Section1.js)

I'm not using `scroll-to-component` package, but the same thing applies.

Forward Refs are supported only in React 16.3 now, you can use [this alternative approach](https://gist.github.com/gaearon/1a018a023347fe1c2476073330cc5509) if you need the feature in lower versions.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. So the first piece of code goes in the Modal component, and the second bit in the <CompX /> component??? I’ll try it out. Thank you!